# useEffect goes in infinite loop when combined useDispatch, useSelector of Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I try to code with react-hook and redux for state management and axios for database requests with Thunk as middleware for handling asynchronicity.I'm having an issue in one component that does a get request to retrieve a list of customers on what used to be `componentwillreceiveprop`

```js
# Action
export const actGetProductRequest = id => dispatch =>
  callApi(`products/${id}`, "GET").then(res =>
    dispatch({
      type: types.EDIT_PRODUCT,
      payload: { product: res.data }
    })
  );

------
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import useForm from "./useForm";
import { actGetProductRequest } from "../../actions";
...
const { history, match } = props;
  const getProduct = useSelector(state => state.itemEditing);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { values, setValues, handleChange, handleSubmit } = useForm(
    getProduct,
    history
  );  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (match) {
      let id = match.params.id;
      dispatch(actGetProductRequest(id));
    }
    setValues(()=>({...getProduct}));
  },[match,dispatch, setValues, getProduct]);
```

And I tried to call API and return the product, but the site always loop render infinite. Continuous rendering cannot be edited the form. like the

[image: gif]

Can anyone please help me out how to resolve this issue...

p.s: with code here, it run ok. But I want to use with redux, and I pass the code calling axios to the dispatch and redux to return the new changed state

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    if (match) {
      let id = match.params.id;
      callApi(`products/${id}`, "GET", null).then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        setValues(()=>({...data}));
      });      
    }
    const clearnUp = () => setValues(false);
    return clearnUp;
  },[match, setValues]);
```

p.s: full code
[code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/elated-hamilton-67hmp?fontsize=14)

Comment: All you have in the dependency array are function references and an object, which are the worst ones. Can be any one of them. history object keeps changing which might effect match.

Comment: @PraneethParuchuri If I don't give the `match,dispatch, setValues, getProduct`, react will show warnings: `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency`.

Comment: Add an answer, let me know if that works.

Comment: The `missing depedency` is just a warning. you get that even when you want to send an empty dependency array.

Answer (score 2):

Just get the id from the history > match

```
  const { history, match } = props;  
  const id = match ? match.params.id : null;
```

You don't need to add `dispatch` to the dependencies. Instead of match, use `id`. And you can skip the method references. Since `setValues` is basically a `setState` call, it can be skipped too (Read React docs). But if you do want to use any function references in dependecies, make sure you  wrap them with `useCallback`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      dispatch(actGetProductRequest(id));
    }
    setValues(()=>({...getProduct}));
  },[id, getProduct]);
```

Your main issue might be with the `match` object. Since, history keeps changing, even if the `id` is the same.

Comment: with useForm: [img](https://imgur.com/Sp7MTMr). if don't have `getProduct` in `dependency array`, and i log the `values` it's not changed and the site don't show the info in form. [form not getProduct](https://imgur.com/UQ9fqOG)

Comment: oh getProduct is not from useForm, I just saw that.

Comment: getProduct is receives value from function useSelector of react-redux

Comment: Well, add the getProduct to the dependencies and try again?

Comment: `[id,dispatch, setValues, getProduct]` should be good dependency list.  If you suspect one of them keeps changing, then add `useEffect(() => console.log("getProduct changed!!"), [getProduct])` to see which dependency is changing

Comment: dispatch is already considered safe and not needed. The image in the first comment here shows that `setValue` is from` `useState`, so that doesn't need to be in there. Read docs says so for `dispatch` and `setState`.

Comment: I think the main issue is with the `match` object. Because history object is not stable.

Comment: @Brandon, @PraneethParuchuri yes, `getProduct` will change, and the `values` will be same change par function `setValues` but the infinite loop error will appear. the form will show the info and I can't edit this form

Comment: @vodanh Did you try with just [id, getProduct] ?

Comment: show a complete example if you want better help.  It is hard to guess where your infinite loop is coming from with only a snippet of code

Comment: @Brandon I uploaded my code, can you check for help me? issue in `\src\pages\ProductActionPage`